# How to drive users to allow pop ups on browsers

Tags: web, popup, browser, dialog, alerts

We're having issues with Popup blockers; preventing some paying clients from seeing the expected dialog.

To combat this issue we either want to add a small line of text near the checkout button that says: 
'Please ensure popups are enabled for this page'

or what other ways are there to make sure users disable popup blockers? Taking into consideration that some users might not know how to enable popups.

Comment: Is the pop-up necessary, or would an in-page display work better?

Comment: People have been trained over many years that popups are bad. Why do you need to force them to use it? Shouldn't you adapt your own site to fit with user expectations rather than trying to get them to ignore their own well-founded concerns?

Comment: Don't have content in pop-ups.

Comment: The only good answer I can come up with is to stop using pop-ups, there are very good reasons why web browsers block them by default.

Comment: >>button that says: Please ensure popups are enabled for this page. A user may not know how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely move away from convincing users to disable blockers. If you really want the content to appear over the top of whatever is on the page then switch from using Javascript pop-ups to modal overlays. Pop-ups are very 1990s and people neither like or trust them, asking users to disable blockers is pretty bad UX at the end of the day.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to modal overlays, which generally work well, you **may** find that for some content opening a new tab/window will do the job. This works well for content that is "big" - e.g., instead of getting a popup with details about a product, they would get a whole new tab with all the details and then they could close it when done. If they are really invested in the product, which presumably they are since they are paying customers, the extra click to close the tab won't be a big deal and, unlike a free site, you don't have to worry about "they click away and never come back".